# Format json array in one line without tabs or line breaks for http post c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, json.net

I'm trying to convert a json array into an string without any tab neither spaces so i can use it on a http post request. The json is the following:

```
[
        {
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "M6",
                    "hour": "15:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M6",
                    "hour": "16:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Descanso",
                    "hour": "16:50",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M9",
                    "hour": "17:10",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M9",
                    "hour": "18:05",
                    "id": "18"
                }
            ],
            "day": "monday"
        },
        {
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "M7",
                    "hour": "15:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M8",
                    "hour": "16:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Descanso",
                    "hour": "16:50",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M6",
                    "hour": "17:10",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M6",
                    "hour": "18:05",
                    "id": "18"
                }
            ],
            "day": "tuesday"
        },
        {
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "hour": "15:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "hour": "16:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Descanso",
                    "hour": "16:50",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M8",
                    "hour": "17:10",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M8",
                    "hour": "18:05",
                    "id": "18"
                }
            ],
            "day": "wednesday"
        },
        {
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "hour": "15:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "hour": "16:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Descanso",
                    "hour": "16:50",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M7",
                    "hour": "17:10",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M7",
                    "hour": "18:05",
                    "id": "18"
                }
            ],
            "day": "thursday"
        },
        {
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "name": "M9",
                    "hour": "15:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M10",
                    "hour": "16:00",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Descanso",
                    "hour": "16:50",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M10",
                    "hour": "17:10",
                    "id": "18"
                },
                {
                    "name": "M10",
                    "hour": "18:05",
                    "id": "18"
                }
            ],
            "day": "friday"
        }
    ]
```

So, i'm trying to parse this jarray to string, but i get:

```
["  [\r\n        {\r\n            \"subjects\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M6\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"15:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M6\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"Descanso\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:50\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M9\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"17:10\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M9\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"18:05\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                }\r\n            ],\r\n            \"day\": \"monday\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"subjects\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M7\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"15:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M8\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"Descanso\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:50\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M6\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"17:10\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M6\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"18:05\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                }\r\n            ],\r\n            \"day\": \"tuesday\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"subjects\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M3\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"15:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M3\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"Descanso\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:50\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M8\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"17:10\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M8\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"18:05\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                }\r\n            ],\r\n            \"day\": \"wednesday\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"subjects\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M3\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"15:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M3\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"Descanso\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:50\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M7\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"17:10\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M7\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"18:05\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                }\r\n            ],\r\n            \"day\": \"thursday\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"subjects\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M9\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"15:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M10\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:00\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"Descanso\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"16:50\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M10\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"17:10\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                },\r\n                {\r\n                    \"name\": \"M10\",\r\n                    \"hour\": \"18:05\",\r\n                    \"id\": \"18\"\r\n                }\r\n            ],\r\n            \"day\": \"friday\"\r\n        }\r\n    ]"]
```

And i need something like

```
[{"subjects":[{"name":"M6","hour":"15:00","id":"18"},{"name":"M6","hour":"16:00","id":"18"},{"name":"Descanso","hour":"16:50","id":"18"},{"name":"M9","hour":"17:10","id":"18"}...
```

Currently i'm using

```
timetable.ToString(Formatting.None).Replace("\t", "");
```

Being timetable my JArray object.

Any suggestion?
Thank your for your time!

Comment: Hi, I see your `.ToString` method works fine to remove all the new lines. Can you specify the requirement and issue you faced? [Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5o2h1X).

Comment: web search "Serialize Unindented JSON" and "How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET" should give you results for JSON.net and Microsoft JsonSerializer.

Comment: How did you construct `timetable`?  It looks as though it contains a single string containing the JSON shown in your question, rather than the results of parsing the JSON shown in your question to a `JToken` hierarchy.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] showing how you construct `timetable`?  See: [ask].  I'm going to venture a guess that you are doing `var timetable = new JArray(someJsonString);` which will result in a `JArray` containing a single string element.  Instead you must do `var timetable = JArray.Parse(someJsonString);` to parse the string as a `JArray` rather than adding it to the array.